# Different behaviour in serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have the following code:

```
ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.dat"));
ArrayList<String> list = null;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Object" + i);
    oo.writeObject(list);
}
oo.close();
```

When I open the test.dat file and `unserialize` the objects, I get all the objects. But if I change my code to this:

```
ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.dat"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.clear(); //clear the earlier objects
    list.add("Object" + i);
    oo.writeObject(list);
}
oo.close();
```

Now when I read the objects, I only get the first one i.e. Object0. Can anyone please explain the behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write an object to an `ObjectOutputStream` twice, then the second time will just be written as a reference to the original data ("that `ArrayList` with id *x* that I wrote before").

This happens **even** if the content of the object has changed (as it does in your case), therefore you will only have 1 full serialization (the first one) and 9 references to that in the second case.

You *could* call [`ObjectOutputStream.reset()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) to discard the list of previously written objects and force it to do a full serialization again.

Comment: Great post! I didn't know that before. Thanks for improving my knowledge of serialization.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in one case, you are using 10 object instances and in the other, you are using 1 instance. Your `oo` is only knowing 1 instance of the object to persist.